# Can a wizard "daisy-chain" Apparate to travel long distances?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition

After reading through a few answers about long distance/international traveling in the HP universe, it seems that apparating over very long distances is not advised/practical/etc due to the extreme unreliability which led me to this question. Why couldn't a wizard apparate a shorter, safe distance (say <50 miles?), then immediately apparate to the next intermediate stop, and so on. For example, notwithstanding the illegality/banning of apparating into another country, couldn't an enterprising wizard apparate over the English Channel to France, then skip his way across Europe to Asia, etc?

Or to take it a step further, why couldn't a wizard theoretically (although probably ill-advised) apparate across the ocean by going whatever the safe apparate distance is and "landing", say 100 feet above the water, then apparating again the next leg before hitting the water, and so on. It makes me wonder if Voldemort's flying spell might be some sort of version of this, akin to a computer script of a bunch of repeating micro-apparates.

Comment: You need to concentrate to apparate. I suspect appearing 100 feet above the ocean and immediately starting to plummet towards it would throw your concentration enough to make apparating a second time difficult. (Also, you’d have less than 3 seconds before you hit the water, at which point you’d be travelling ~60mph. Messy.)

Comment: Then appear 1,000 feet above the water or whatever height to give enough time apparate again. You get the point. And after some practice/experimentation before attempting. Out of all the wizards ever born, I can't imagine a few out there haven't experimented with apparating tricks like yo-yoing up & down, back & forth, etc. Hell, I would. There's probably world record attempts/competitions for fastest consecutive apparates or longest/shortest distances, or heaviest, etc.

Comment: @iMerchant - I feel like this is the sort of thing that the wizarding Darwin Awards celebrates. "**Local wizard stupid enough to apparate 1000ft above the ground. Relatives say '*He was trying something out*'"**

Comment: Isn't part of apperating focusing intently on your destination? It's difficult to focus on "that specific spot of air 1000 ft above sea level". I will say that I could see apparation stations set up where they do this over land though. Apparate to the station where they have a poster of the next station to focus on or something

Answer (score 7):

**Why couldn't they?**

It's definitely possible.  There doesn't seem to be any reason that it should be impossible.  Of course, there is the risk of Splinching or ending up in the wrong spot.  And also the fact that if you Apparate too many times in a row, you'll probably throw up.  But it's definitely possible to do this, although the second idea is sort of stupid.

**Why don't they?**

There are other, better ways to get places in the wizarding world.  Firstly, Floo powder.  Although this requires a fireplace at the other end, it's much quicker than your ideas and doesn't require a license or any magical skill.  Second is the broomstick.  While it might be hard, we know from Jocunda Sykes, the woman who flew across the Atlantic on a broomstick in 1935, that it is possible.  Again, it requires no license; but it is as long or longer than the Apparition idea, and requires that the user has a broom.  Third is the Portkey, which can basically take you anywhere really fast even if they are a pain to register.

There are no examples of this in the book because they never leave Britain.  This could be used commonly in the magical world, but it does have its flaws.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why they technically couldn't.  However, apparating requires you to be able to visualize your target.  For long distances, it's pretty unlikely you'll be able to visualize a string of points along the way within apparating range of each other.  The only other option then would be to apparate to points you can see from your current location, which would be not all that long a distance at all between jumps, especially in areas with buildings or trees.  Apparating is also not an effortless act, as seen when the students train for their Apparition test, though it seems to get easier with practice.  This seems to me it would end up being rather slow and tiring compared to just flying on a broomstick.

Comment: You don't exactly need to visualize it, you just have to have it fixed in your mind.  For example, if I wanted to get to Hogwarts, I could just think Hogwarts Hogwarts Hogwarts in my head and then Apparate their without knowing what it looks like.

Comment: Disagree about being slow. Apparating even 20 miles every 10 seconds or so would be much faster than broomstick. Obviously a portkey would be most efficient and quickest, but they are hard to attain. Don't disagree about it being tiring however. I guess it depends on how many mana points someone has on how far they could go. Lol

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out I don't see why you couldn't. However for the case of appearing 100 feet above the water, I think there seems to be a problem. :

> “The important things to remember when Apparating are the three D’s!” said Twycross. “Destination, Determination, Deliberation!
>
> “Step one: fix your mind firmly upon the desired destination,” said Twycross. “In this case, the interior of your hoop. Kindly concentrate upon that destination now.”
>
> “Step two,” said Twycross, “focus your determination to occupy the visualised space! Let your yearning to enter it flood from your mind to every particle of your body! “
>
> “Step three,” called Twycross, “only when I give the command... turn on the spot, feeling your way into nothingness, moving with deliberation. On my command, now... one —”
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 18</sub>

Here we see that while apparating you are supposed to move or turn deliberately. However, this cannot be done while 100 feets above in air due to lack of an external force (assuming that Newton's laws of motion are applicable to wizards and witches while they are not using magic.).

Comment: Didn't Hermione Disapparate while falling in Deathly Hallows?  When she blasted away part of the floor in the Lovegood home and the three fell into the room below, I'm sure Harry felt them all "turn" before they had a chance to hit the ground.

Comment: @Pastychomper As far as I remember, Hermione blasted apart the floor (You might be right, but I always assumed it was only blasted apart partially) and apparated while still standing on the ground. However,  I am not really sure, and I do not have the books presently. Can you please quote the passage here?

Comment: I've consulted the book and Hermione definitely did Disapparate in mid-air. The book says "They fell like boulders [...] Hermione twisted in mid-air [...]". Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 21: The Tale of Three Brothers.

Comment: @Roberto If that is so, I stand corrected. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks @Roberto, I don't have the books any more either.  Your quotes also helped me find a longer excerpt that got me thinking:  When they reached their destination, "Harry fell ... onto grass", as if he still had the momentum (and maybe the height) he had before Apparating.  If momentum is conserved during a "jump" then "daisy-chaining" without landing on something solid would mean falling faster and faster, making landing hard. It might also explain the range limit: a few miles won't hurt, but try Apparating 90° east and you'll be flying upwards at up to 1,040 mph.